# MySql version of sys.dm_os_sys_info

Tags: mysql, hardware

Is there a mysql version of sys.dm_os_sys_info. 
I know of show status and show variables, but I'm looking for hardware cpu and ram numbers. 
Or will I just have to ask the Admins?

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux OS? For linux, from OS Command Line, top will reveal RAM and iostat -xm 5 3 may reveal core/cpu count.  You may find 'cat /proc/meminfo' report to be helpful.  Use of MySQLtuner.pl (perl) script may be helpful for you.

Comment: @WilsonHauck using a linux os; i'm a crossover dba; sme mssqlsrv needing to learn mysql quickly. I did get access to some OS level health reports.

Answer (score 0):

The nearest to your question performance schema

> The Performance Schema provides a way to inspect internal execution of the server at runtime.
>
> The Performance Schema monitors server events. An “event” is anything the server does that takes time and has been instrumented so that timing information can be collected.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema.html